# Javascript file embedded by Disqus ("alfie.f51946af45e0b561c60f768335c9eb79.js") and redirect in its code

Tags: javascript, redirect, disqus

I just noticed this JavaScript file is embedded in many pages of my site where Disqus comments is enabled.

http://a.disquscdn.com/next/embed/alfie.f51946af45e0b561c60f768335c9eb79.js

Any idea what is its purpose?

I found out that it automatically adds a click event listener to every link (both internal and external links) and the click event does some redirection. It was not a significant problem until I realized the redirection was affecting many links to an external website I have in my site and all of them ended up in the home page.

Its not a matter of my URL's build to the external website in href or parameters as copy pasting the URL directly into browser (no redirection) works fine.

Is this a Disqus feature for tracking or something that can be configured?

[image: Screenshot of click event listener (Firefox debug)]

Comment: I had the same "problem" after using disqus for almost two years. It seems to affect only links to eCommerce (so some people might never notice that happening in their website)

Answer (score 5):

It's the "Affiliate links" enabled option in Disqus Setup > Advanced

https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/851667-affiliate-guide

Answer (score 1):

Updated help article link:

https://help.disqus.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2425431-how-to-disable-affiliate-linking

> Affiliate linking is an optional feature that automatically replaces
>   outbound product links on your site with affiliate links,
>
> To disable or enable affiliate linking, visit the Admin > Settings >
>   Advanced.